# Como executar o método somente após término da função anterior

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript

Tenho o código abaixo, porém o método `showVideo()` é executado e segue a execução ao mesmo tempo do código abaixo dele, sem esperar o `showVideo()` terminar, o que ocorre é devido a execução simultânea o valor setado no storage não fica correto.

```
buscaBonus() {

     this.servicoGeral.showVideo(); //esse metodo chama o `addTempo()` que por 
     sua vez chama um localStorage.setItem para setar o tempo ganho, e o código 
     abaixo recupera esse valor para mostrar em tela. Só deveria executar o 
     código abaixo após o `showVideo()`.

     if (localStorage.getItem("segundos") == undefined) {
       this.totalBonus = localStorage.getItem("segundos");
     }    

     let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Você ganhou 5 segundos de bônus!',
      message: 'Poderá utilizar e até acumular para jogar qualquer fase.',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Entendi ',
          handler: () => {
            return true;
          }
        }
      ],
      enableBackdropDismiss: false
      });    
      alert.present();      
    }

     showvideo(): Promise<boolean>{    
        const rewardVideoConfig: AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig = {
          id: 'ca-app-pub-1390341047819209/6782590495',
          isTesting: true,
          autoShow: true
        }

        this.admobFree.rewardVideo.config(rewardVideoConfig);
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {

          rewardVideoClose = this.admobFree.on(this.admobFree.events.REWARD_VIDEO_CLOSE).subscribe(() => {

          });
          rewardVideoReward = this.admobFree.on(this.admobFree.events.REWARD_VIDEO_REWARD).subscribe(() => {
            this.addTempo();
            rewardVideoReward.unsubscribe();
          });

          this.admobFree.rewardVideo.prepare()
            .then(() => { })
            .catch(() => {
              loading.dismiss();
              resolve(false);
            });
        }); 
     } 
      addTempo() {
         if (localStorage.getItem("segundos") == null) {
           this.tempoSegundos = 5
         } else {
           let tempo = localStorage.getItem("segundos");
           this.tempoSegundos = (parseInt(tempo) + 5)
         }
         let tempo: string;
         tempo = this.tempoSegundos.toString()
         localStorage.setItem('segundos', tempo);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Qual seria a a primeira função que executa?

Tentar chamar o `this.addTempo()`como nesse exemplo, usando um callback.

```
funcao() {
  let loader = this._loaderCtrl.create();
  loader
    .present()
        .then(() => {
           .subscribe(
              () => {
              let toast = this._toastCtrl.create({
                message: "mensagem",
                duration: 3000
              });
              toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
                this.addTempo()
              });
          toast.present();
        loader.dismiss();
 }
```

**Exemplo com loading:**

```
loader.dismiss(()=>{
    this.addTempo()
 });
```

Comment: Essa função deve ser observable? estou tentando utilizar seu código para fazer um teste e ocorre erro no subscribe.

Comment: Tentar usar sem o subscribe mesmo, foi apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Acho que meu problema está antes então, pois eu tenho um método que chama esse 
showVideo:
 buscaBonus() {  
    this.servicoGeral.showVideo();
    //NESSE MOMENTO ANTES DE TERMINAR A FUNÇÃO ACIMA JÁ EXECUTA O CÓDIGO ABAIXO    

      this.totalBonus = localStorage.getItem("segundos");

//E CONSEQUENTEMENTE AINDA NÃO TEM VALOR GRAVADO NO STORAGE
  }

Comment: Queria formatar o código acima, mas não consegui

Comment: Consegue editar e colocar no post? talvez fique melhor de entender

Comment: feito, acho que mudou até o problema agora, refiz toda a pergunta.

Comment: `this.admobFree.rewardVideo.prepare()
            .then(() => {this.addTempo })
            .catch(() => {
              loading.dismiss();
              resolve(false);
            });`

Comment: não funciona amigo

Comment: chamando no prepare o vídeo não foi assistido ainda e não deveria passar pelo `addTempo()`, o certo seria nesse evento `REWARD_VIDEO_REWARD`, mas já fiz com promisse e as funções são executadas uma atras da outra não esperando o término da primeira. Já tentei várias formas.

Answer (score -1):

Pode criar uma barreira, mesmo método utilizado em requisições assíncronas, da uma olhada, talvez possa te ajudar.

```
var simpleBarrier = require('simple-barrier'),
fs = require('fs');

// create a barrier instance
var barrier = simpleBarrier();

// load some files, let the barrier handle the callbacks:
fs.readFile('foo.txt', barrier.waitOn());
fs.readFile('bar.txt', barrier.waitOn());
fs.readFile('baz.txt', barrier.waitOn());

// add a callback for when all files are loaded
barrier.endWith(function( results ){

   // Results is an array of the values given by fs.readFile
   // the array is in the order that barrier.waitOn() was called, regardless of the 
   // order they were loaded in
   console.log('foo, bar, and baz are:', results.join('\n'));
});
```

Fonte: *https://github.com/jimhigson/simple-barrier*

Comment: O ideal é trazer as informações importantes dos links para a respostas considerando que elas podem ser alteradas/excluídas na fonte, o que vai acabar deixando um vácuo na sua resposta. Claro que o link permanece como referência.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda amigo, mas ainda não consegui resolver o meu problema, infelizmente, fiz de várias formas para barras o processamento e mesmo assim nada adiantou.